# Easy way to add EU cookie notification to multiple Drupal websites?

Tags: cookies

I have 20+ Drupal sites that I have to add Cookie notifs to. Is there an easy/batch/automated way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

Check out [EU Cookie Compliance](http://drupal.org/project/eu-cookie-compliance) for your notifications.

> This module intends to deal with the EU Directive on Privacy and
>   Electronic Communications that comes into effect in the UK on 26th May
>   2012. From this date on, you run the risk of enforcement action if you are not compliant or visibly working towards compliance.

Automating the process however is quite localised depending on your server setup, and would probably be considered off topic.

Answer (score 2):

There is a module for that: [EU Cookie Compliance](http://drupal.org/project/eu-cookie-compliance)